# How to iterate a nested model and generate Elements based on that

Tags: sapui5

As the title states, I do have a Model, with `Choices` property which is nested.

```js
let modelExample = {
  0: {
    "Description": "Example 0",
    "Choices": [ "0", "1", "2" ]
  },
  1: {
    "Description": "Example 1",
    "Choices": [ "0", "1", "2" ]
  },
  2: {
    "Description": "Example 2",
    "Choices": [ "0", "1", "2" ]
  }
};
```

It should construct a Table with `Description` as a `Label` and `Choices` as `Buttons`, something like:

[image: Table with Choices]

Table:

```xml
<Table items="{modelExample>/}">
  <columns>
    <Column>
      <Text text="Description" />
    </Column>
    <Column>
      <Text text="Choices" />
    </Column>
  </columns>
  <ColumnListItem>
    <Label text="{modelExample>Description}" />
    <SegmentedButton selectedButton="none">
      <items>
        <SegmentedButtonItem text="{modelExample>Choices/0}" />
        <SegmentedButtonItem text="{modelExample>Choices/1}" />
        <SegmentedButtonItem text="{modelExample>Choices/2}" />
      </items>
    </SegmentedButton>
  </ColumnListItem>
</Table>
```

**Issue:** As it stands right now, it does work in this way. The problem is that; if you were to extend `Choices` to 20+ entries, it would also require to add 20+ `SegmentedButtonItem`, and that is something I try to avoid.

**Question:** How to generically generate `Buttons` based on a nested `Choices`-Property / How to also iterate through nested `Choices`?

Answer (score 2):

Set your `SegementedButton` item path to `{modelExample>Choices}`. The path of your text property in `SegmentedButtonItem` is `modelExample>` because there's no key/value in your array.

```xml
<SegmentedButton items="{
  path: 'modelExample>Choices',
  templateShareable: false
}">
  <items>
    <SegmentedButtonItem text="{modelExample>}" />
  </items>
</SegmentedButton>
```

In case of an array like `[{0:"0"},{1:"1"},{2:"2"}]` (Your example in your comment isn't valid) you should prepare you're array to receive a static property.

```js
    const aArray = [{0:"0"},{1:"1"},{2:"2"}];
    const aPreparedArray = aArray.map(oObject =>{ //Loop through array
      for(let key in oObject){ //Loop through object
        return {propertyName: oObject[key]}; /return object with a static property
      }
    });
    modelExample.setProperty("/", aPreparedArray); //Set array to model
```

Then you could use:

```xml
    <SegmentedButton items="{
      path: 'modelExample>Choices',
      templateShareable: false
    }">
      <items>
        <SegmentedButtonItem text="{modelExample>propertyName}" />
      </items>
    </SegmentedButton>
```

Comment: What if there was a key value Pair and the Choices looked like this [0:"0",1:"1",2:"2"] etc. ?

Comment: Dynamic binding isn't possible in SAPUI5 XML Views. You'll have to use JS for that. I think it would make sense to prepare the array beforehand to have a static property. I've edited my answer.

Comment: After `modelExample.setProperty("/", aPreparedArray);` -> modelData changed for some reason to the `aPreparedArray` that you put forward, which leads to actually 3 `rows` being generated rather then, three `buttons`.